# Why second tap on edittext field causes application error?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have one edittext field that gets a number. When the field is clear, I can touch it as many times as I want. If even one character appears and I close the keyboard, the second time I tap edittext the app will get an get runtime.

I tried to find some method or anything to help me in the Android documentation about EditText but I didn't find it.

Here is my code

Java

```java
package com.example.aplikacja_testowa;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CallSettings extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView textView;
    private EditText editText;
    private Button saveButton;

    public static final String SHARED_PREFS = "sharedPrefs";
    public static final String TEXT = "text";
    //public static final

    private String text;

    ////////////////
    int dem=0;
    int them;
    int selectTheme = 2;
    ////////////////

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        them=SmsSettings.loadData(CallSettings.this, "style.txt", null, dem);
        selectTheme = them;
        Log.i("TAG", "onCreate selectTheme: "+selectTheme);
        FontSettings.setDynamicTheme(CallSettings.this, selectTheme);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_call_settings);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.callInstruction);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.textPhoneNumber);
        saveButton = findViewById(R.id.save_button);
    }

    public void savePhoneNumber(View v){
        SmsSettings.saveData(this, "callnumber.txt", editText, 0);
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.number_saved, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

XML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CallSettings">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/callInstruction"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/after_ent_the_num"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textPhoneNumber"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textPhoneNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/inp_ph_num"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/save_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:onClick="savePhoneNumber"
        android:text="@string/save_sett"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textPhoneNumber" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
E/MessageQueue-JNI: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:190)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:766)
        at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:525)
        at android.widget.Editor$InsertionPointCursorController.getHandle(Editor.java:5070)
        at android.widget.Editor$InsertionPointCursorController.show(Editor.java:5049)
        at android.widget.Editor.onTouchUpEvent(Editor.java:2136)
        at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:8510)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9943)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:411)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1810)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3061)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:70)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:373)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:10163)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4434)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4302)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3849)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3902)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3868)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3995)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3876)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4052)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3849)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3902)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3868)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3876)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3849)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6210)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6184)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6145)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6313)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.aplikacja_testowa, PID: 14480
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:190)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:766)
        at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:525)
        at android.widget.Editor$InsertionPointCursorController.getHandle(Editor.java:5070)
        at android.widget.Editor$InsertionPointCursorController.show(Editor.java:5049)
        at android.widget.Editor.onTouchUpEvent(Editor.java:2136)
        at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:8510)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9943)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2669)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2358)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:411)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1810)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3061)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:70)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:373)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:10163)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4434)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4302)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3849)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3902)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3868)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3995)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3876)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4052)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3849)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3902)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3868)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3876)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3849)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6210)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6184)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6145)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6313)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Comment: please include the stack trace from the crash. Or best, first read it **carefully** yourself and see if that's not self explanatory one

Comment: also, are you still seeing problems when you comment out `FontSettings.setDynamicTheme()`?

Comment: so it fails without setDynamicTheme()? what is the default application theme you got set? anything custom? can you disable it?

Comment: Thank you for help. That was setDynamicTheme().

Comment: The default theme is available but is not part of what is being changed. The idea was to take a number representing the value of one of three font sizes from a text file. Yes, theme was customized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently whatever theme details is the `FontSettings.setDynamicTheme()` changing, it ends up leaving  your widget in invalid or incomplete state, or with styles referring to non existing resources.

My blind guess about why it works when there's no content entered into EditText is because if there's no content, the widget for example won't need to draw some of its elements. So you can make your empty EditText focused as many times as you want and nothing bad would happen, but if there's any content and the style i.e. refers to resources that are missing (like drawables, fonts etc), then it will crash with `ResourceNotFoundException`. I guess `FontSettings` is external project, so I'd check for an update fist, then I'd inspect the styles it tries to apply.

Comment: I used the wrong parent to change the fonts in themes.xml. Thank you for your help.